# Discovering embedded device in local network?

Tags: android, sockets, networking, embedded, broadcast

I am trying to build an embedded device that would be connected to a router.
But I want to be able to know if the device is connected to the router or not using a PC or Mobile.

For example:
How can the PC detect if the google chromecast is connected on the same network or not ?

- Do I need to communicate with each IP in the network on a specific port to ask ?
- Or do I need to let the embedded device broadcast some information every N seconds ?

Thanks,

Comment: Back up a a bit. What protocol is the device using and, if TCP, is it a client or server?

Comment: One scenario would be that you know your embedded device's network addres ([IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) or [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address)) and you try to "ping" your device (from the PC or mobile) through a pinging protocol like [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol). If the device is connected to the router and accessible on your network then it will "echo" back. If you don't get the "echo" message back within a timeout then the device is not connected. Is it applicable in your case?

Comment: @MartinJames The device can use tcp/udp and its a server device.

Comment: @xmojmr in my case, I want the embedded device to introduce itself to the network without knowing the IP. Also, multiple devices of the same type might exist in the network I want to detect them explicitly

Comment: What is the expected distance between the device-router-PC? (e.g. Bluetooth range?) Can you modify the router software or it's supposed to be a 3rd party black-box router?

Comment: @xmojmr  embedded device uses Wifi to communicate with the router, is there any network protocol to help the device introduce itself ?

Comment: There may be some problems with overcoming the "hops" in case of too many general-purpose routing elements between your device and the PC. It seems that you may utilize some kind of network topology discovery protocol like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Neighbor_Discovery and once the PC can see the target device then http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol may be the way to query/update configuration of your device in an uniform manner. Android-specific answer? Useful Google keywords? I don't know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any case you should consider doing a [Gratuitous](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Gratuitous_ARP) [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) on your embedded device. A gratuitous ARP will announce to all of the devices on your LAN that a new device has joined so they can update their ARP cache.

As far as a PC/Mobile device discovering your embedded device goes, you have a few options:

#### Option 1

If we can assume that this is a typical flat home network where all of the devices are on a single subnet and there is one gateway *router* * then you can give your embedded device a unique [OUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizationally_unique_identifier). If you intend to sell this device you will need to [apply for an OUI with the IEEE anyway](http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/public.html) unless whoever made your chipset supplies it with a MAC address already. Your PC/Mobile app can periodically check its ARP cache for an OUI that matches the unique OUI that you expect.

This will not work if the network is not flat and there are multiple routed subnets or VLANS. Here is a possible scenario: Lets suppose your embedded device connects to a client bridge range extender. If your PC/Mobile app is on the main access point it will never see the MAC address of the embedded device - instead it will see the MAC address of the client bridge. Multiple IPs will be mapped to the client bridge because the client bridge and the client bridge will be switching packets.

*I put the term router in italics because most home routers are merely doing NAT between the WAN/LAN and the LAN side of the router operates like a layer 2 switch.

#### Option 2

You can do a broadcast ping request, eg. ping xxx.xxx.xxx.255. You'll get a response back from all devices that will accept a broadcast ping request. Just make sure your device does. Then once you have a list of IP addresses you can attempt to open a TCP socket over the arbitrary port of your choosing with all of those IP addresses and then send some unique handshake packet. Your embedded device should be listening over this port and should have some unique reply to this unique packet. Most of the devices on the lan should generally not allow this socket to open, but if they do they should not understand the unique handshake message you send.

#### Option 3

Send a broadcast UDP datagram with some unique handshake payload. Then your embedded device should reply to the sender of this broadcast UDP packet with some unique response. After this response has been received by your PC/Mobile app you can then open a TCP socket with the IP address the response came from.

Comment: That's great and should really simplify the problem too much ! As another suggestion does it make sense to communicate with each IP on a specific port to see if its the device or not by sending hello msg for example. Is this done by industry ? Your answer is great thanks alot !

Comment: @Xedar Yes, you can do that, and it is done in industry. That is exactly what we do on one of our products. The device acts as a wifi access point and we have a special application layer protocol. We attempt to open a TCP socket on a given port, if that works we then send our first query to initiate a session, and if that fails we will throw an exception and give the user a message that says we cannot connect to the device. Generally at this point it is safe to assume the device is ours based on the SSID, so it is already on a list of devices on our UI, but you get the drift.

Comment: @Xedar When you think about it... thats exactly what you do whenever you open a web browser. You are opening a TCP socket with a server on port 80 and issuing HTTP_GET. The TCP socket will either fail (either you will be rejected or you just wont get an ACK) or you will open the socket. Following this your post will be issued and that may or may not succeed. You will either see the page you expect or you may get a 404 error or something. So what you are proposing is the way it's always been done :)

Comment: Great ! These information worth alot ! This is the way I am going to implement it, Thanks alot Nick !

Comment: @Xedar I had another idea. You can send out a broadcast Udp datagram "hello" and have your device reply "hi from sn1234" directly to the sender. Then you will have the ip of all of your devices because they will know to respond to that datagram. Then you can start your tcp session.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help, now the idea became more mature in my mind. Could you please add the last comment of yours to the answer ?

Comment: @xedar I refactored my answer.